# Issues running Max function and Order by in snowflake sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake and I am trying to run an sql query that would extract the maximum Datetime for each ID. Below is a sample of my data

Table name: final_extract

| id | datetime | ip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2022-02-03 11:37:58:000 | 62.44.134.97 |
| 222 | 2021-02-03 11:37:58:000 | 88.44.134.96 |
| 111 | 2022-02-01 11:37:58:000 | 22.44.134.97 |
| 111 | 2021-02-03 11:37:58:000 | 69.44.134.97 |

what I want to achieve

| id | datetime | ip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2022-02-03 11:37:58:000 | 62.44.134.97 |
| 222 | 2021-02-03 11:37:58:000 | 88.44.134.96 |

The code below doesn't seem to achieve what I want.

```
select "id", MAX("datetime") As LastLoginDateTime, "ip "
from final_extract
group by "id ","ip "
order by MAX("datetime") DESC
limit 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query doesn't work because you have a different ip for each row, you have to decide which to choose.
Check it out, I choose the last value from ip:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT id
     , MAX(datetime) OVER(PARTITION BY id) As LastLoginDateTime
     , LAST_VALUE(ip) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY datetime) AS ip
  FROM final_extract
 ORDER BY LastLoginDateTime DESC
 LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thats alot bossman for your response, but please what does the OVER (PARTITION BY id) mean

Comment: OVER is a window function clause, this is similar to GROUP BY but at the level of one column. If you are not familiar with the window functions, I recommend that you read: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html

Answer (score 0):

Michael's answer is good, but if you have many rows and wish to pick some rowa and exclude the rest, then the [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) option works very nicely, and using [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html) to choose the preferred row per set.

```
SELECT *
FROM VALUES 
    (111, '2022-02-03 11:37:58:000', '62.44.134.97'),
    (222, '2021-02-03 11:37:58:000', '88.44.134.96'),
    (111, '2022-02-01 11:37:58:000', '22.44.134.97'),
    (111, '2021-02-03 11:37:58:000', '69.44.134.97')
    v(id, datetime, ip_address)
QUALIFY row_number() over(partition by id order by datetime desc) = 1
```

thus for you table, and columns:

```
select id, datetime AS lastlogindatetime, "ip "
from final_extract
QUALIFY row_number() over ( partition by id order by datetime desc) = 1
order by 2 DESC
limit 10
```

is rather concise.